# string alignment in perl / match alignment

Tags: string, perl, alignment

I have two strings $dna1 and $dna2. Print the two strings as concatenated, and then print the second string lined up over its copy at the end of the concatenated strings. For example, if the input
strings are AAAA and TTTT, print:

```
AAAATTTT
    TTTT
```

this is a self exercise question .. not a homework ,

i tried using index
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

```
$a ='AAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTT';
$b ='TTTTTTTTTT';
print $a,"\n";
print ''x index($a,$b),$b,"\n";
```

but it is not working as needed .help please

Comment: In your text, you say the input is AAAA and TTTT. In your code, you have AAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTT and TTTTTTTTTT. Which one is it? Is it already concatenated or not?

Comment: There are 9 T in your `$a` string and 10 T in your `$b` string. You will never find 10 Ts in `$a`.

Answer (score 2):

Start by checking what `index($a,$b)` is returning... Perhaps you should pick a `$b` that's actually in `$a`!

Then realise that concatenating 10 instances of an empty string is an empty string, not 10 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fun little exercise. I did this:

```
perl -lwe'$a="AAAA"; $b="TTTT"; $c = $a.$b; $i = index($c,$b) + length($b); 
          print $c; printf "%${i}s\n", $b;'
AAAAAAATTTT
       TTTT
```

Note that generally speaking, using the variable names `$a` through `$c` is a bad idea, and only acceptable here because it is a one-liner. `$a` and `$b` are also reserved variable names used with `sort`.

Comment: `$i = length($c);` would be simpler.  Printing `' ' x length($a)` spaces would be simpler yet.